# Заголовок BCC в функции mail

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Пишу рассыльщик писем. Столкнулся с такой проблемой - надо рассылать по большому числу подписчиков (>500), соответственно это требует больших ресурсов сервера, если рассылать таким вот способом:

```
$count = count($all_mail_array);
for($c=0;$count>c;$c++){
содержание письма, тема письма
mail($all_mail_array[$c], $tema, $body);
}
```

Т.к. сервер постоянно открывает и закрывает соединение. Покопавшись в глубине всего этого, нашел информацию по заголовкам Bcc, CC, а также о том, что можно делать так:

```
$to = "<mail1@mail.ru>, <mail2@mail.ru>"
```

Но т.к. палить все адреса подписчиков не хочется, то решил использовать Bcc. Так вот. **Вопрос!** Будет ли большая нагрузка на сервер, если я сделаю так:
$count = count($all_mail_array);
    for($c=0;$count>c;$c++){
    содержание письма, тема письма
    $header .= "Bcc: $all_mail_array[$c]\r\n"; 
    }
    mail('', $tema, $body, $header);

Тестовую отправку делать не хочется. Хочу, чтобы с первого раза все уже шло нормально. И не хочу положить сервер...) Те, кто уже пробовал использовать подобную конструкцию, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [документации на PHP mail](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php) написано, что список *TO* обязательный. Собственно из него и будут получены адреса получателей (RCPT TO: ) SMTP протокола.

Поля CC и BCC относятся к заголовкам и являются неким указанием (hint) почтовому (POP, IMAP) клиенту на то, **что показать читателю**. Это я кратко, без ряда деталей.

Нагрузка на сервер:

Безусловно лучше посылать списком, но слишком длинный некоторые сервера могут и не принимать. Так что без тестов не обойтись. Я бы резал список получателей, скажем по 100. Дополнительная оптимизация - это группировка адресов получателей по домену.

Нормальный сервер уронить таким способом не получится, а если какой упал, то туда ему и дорога.

Comment: Я пробовал список To устанавливать как '', а несколько адресов перечислять в Bcc - все отправляется. Спасибо за совет про разбивку.

Comment: Значит конкретная реализация берет объединение адресов из всех доступных источников. Лично я не стал бы закладываться, что такое поведение будет во всех реализациях.